# to go with save site as a template, web template or site definition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, site-definition

I have to create a generic site template which has few tabs in the home page and on click of these links/tabs in this site template it will navigate to the sub sites created under that[this generic site template shud contain 3 sub sites - 
[1 blog, 1 search center sub site, meeting workspace as tabs in the site template’s top navigation] and
a) 2 Doc Libs
b) 2 splists by default present in this site template [ most prob. its a team site template]
 What should be the correct approach for creating this site template:
 I have thought of implementing using:
 a) save site as a template and upload this wsp into the solution collection gallery
 b) create a  web template having the above subsites and doc libs and splists
 c) last option is to create a  site definition [ complex ]

Which one should i choose, assuming that, there would be future changes from customer side in the site template.like, adding a new splist, sp doclic or a new custom web part.
in that case, adding a new addtion to the already existing site template will not affect/reflect the already running sites' strcuture.

Only those new sites which is created  based on the updated site template would be having the new additions  implemented.

help is highly appreciated.